# What is the method Arrays.free?

Tags: java

I stumbled across this in the API last night and tried to use it, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it. It's in the `Arrays` class and is called `free`.

Comment: please show us your sourcecode

Comment: Please rephrase, I do not understand the question.

Comment: Are you sure you are not referring to Arrays.fill(..) ?

Comment: There is no `Free` (or `free`) method in `java.util.Arrays` (or `java.lang.reflect.Array`) - please give detail of where you found the method.

Comment: There is no ``Arrays.free()``, what API version are you using?

Comment: You are probably not using `java.util.Arrays`. Can you check the import and give the fully qualified name of this class?

Comment: Sounds like C/C++ malloc/free thing! You sure you are not thinking about C/C++?

Comment: I didn't originally say Arrays, I said [i]Array[/i]. However, someone felt the need to edit it without asking me to do so first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've stumbled across [`java.sql.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html) instead - this has a [`free()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html#free--) method.

> This method frees the Array object and releases the resources that it holds.

Comment: That's the description to the method. I used the indented array class in the original post on purpose. So may I ask how to actually use this, do I need to import java.sql.Array?

Comment: Yes, if you are sure that that is actually the Array class you wish to use in your program - obviously I don't know as you haven't included any code in your original post.

Answer (score 3):

[`java.utils.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does not have a method called `free`. So the answer to your question is: you don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Arrays.free()`, what API are you using?

If you are referring to the [java.sql.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html#free()) interface, the documentation for `free()` states:

> This method frees the `Array` object and releases the resources that it holds. The object is invalid once the free method is called.
>
> After free has been called, any attempt to invoke a method other than free will result in a `SQLException` being thrown. If free is called multiple times, the subsequent calls to free are treated as a no-op.